# Hadoop Load and Store

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

When I am trying to run a Pig script which has two "store" to the same file this way

```
store Alert_Message_Count into 'out';
store Warning_Message_Count into 'out';
```

It hangs, I mean it does not proceed after showing 50% done.

Is this wrong? Cant we store both the results in the same file(folder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally Hadoop MapReduce won't allow you to save job output to a folder that already exists, so i would guess that this isn't possible either (seeing as Pig translates the commands into a series of M/R steps) - but i would expect some form of error message rather than it just to hang.

If you open the cluster job tracker, and look at the logs for the task, does the log yield anything of note which can help diagnose this further?

Might also be worth checking with the pig mailing lists (if you haven't already)

If you want to append one dataset to another, use the `union` keyword:

```
grunt> All_Count = UNION Alert_Message_Count, Warning_Message_Count;
grunt> store All_Count into 'out';
```

Comment: Yes it now throws an exception, but after a long time.As you said it does not allow writing to a output file which already exists. When I use two separate files, it works fine.
In that case what is the way to append/write the results to a single file?

Comment: Do the two outputs have the same 'schema'? If so look at the union keyword - http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/advanced_pig_latin.html

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes they have the same schema.UNION can be worked out for these.

Comment: Would it be a good practice to use load the output files so generated and then extract information from that?
I mean I am using something like this
A = load 'Number_By_Time/part-r-00000' using PigStorage(' ');
B = group A by $2;
C = foreach B generate group, COUNT($1);
I was just thinking whether Number_By_Time/part-r-00000 would cause any issues later on? Right now I have no issues, but would it be advisable to use something like this?

Comment: Not sure i understand your question

Comment: I am writing a pig script and in that I store some result into a file. Then I load once again the same output file and do the further processing, like this
Alert_Message_Day_Order = foreach Alert_Message_Day generate group,COUNT($1);
store Alert_Message_Time_Order into 'Number_By_Time';
store Alert_Message_Day_Order into 'Number_By_Day';
A = load 'Number_By_Time/part-r-00000' using PigStorage(' ');

I have continued in the next comment...

Comment: I wanted to know if this is fine? I mean using the output file so generated, i.e. here when I do  "store Alert_Message_Time_Order into 'Number_By_Time';" I get an output folder with a file in it named "Number_By_Time/part-r-00000". Then I LOAD this file and do the further processing.
i.e. "A = load 'Number_By_Time/part-r-00000' using PigStorage(' ');"
So, I wanted to know if this can be done? It works fine, but just wanted to know if this can be done.

Comment: Sure, if you want to store off intermediate results then this is perfectly acceptable, also means you are able to continue processing from a 'checkpoint'

Comment: Yes, its not just storing but also immediately using the stored results for further LOADING.

Answer (score 1):

HDFS does not have append mode. So in most cases where you are running map-reduce programs, the output file is opened once, data is written and then closed. Assuming this approach you can not write data simultaneously onto the same file.

Try writing to separate files and check if the map-red programs do not hang. If they still do, then there are some other issues.

You can obtain the result and map-reduce logs to analyze what went wrong.

[Edit:]

You can not write to the same file or append to an existing file. The HDFS Append feature is a work in progress.

To work on this you can do two things:

1) If you have the same schema content in both Alert_Message_Count and Warning_Message_Count, you could use union as suggested by Chris.

2) Do post processing when the schema is not the same. That is write a map reduce program to merge the two separate outputs into one.

Comment: When I write to different files, it does it without any problem.
What can be done so as to append/write multiple results to a single file?

Comment: @Nikhil Desai: See edited answer and also Chris's answer. You can not use append but there are solutions based on existing constraint.

Comment: Thanks. For now, Union should help me. Anyway I will look into the second option too.